# Installing custom Screenlets

Tags: 14.04, screenlets

This may be obscure, but how do I add custom screenlets to Screenlets? There are tons of custom screenlets available on Gnome-Look.org, like [this countdown timer](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php?content=140959/), but I'm having a hard time finding out how to install them.

Best regards,
Moss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In the `Screenlets` app, choose `Install` on the left.
2. Select `Install Screenlet` then click <kbd>OK</kbd>.
3. Browse to downloaded `.tar.gz` file.
4. Click downloaded `.tar.gz` file, then click <kbd>Open</kbd>.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I had extracted the contents of the .tar.gz, no wonder I couldn't install it.